# Cann't delete VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox

I have VirtualBox 5.2.8. I try to delete it through the control panel, but every time the process rolls back, and the program is not deleted. How can this be fixed?

Sorry for my English)))

Comment: This is not the newest version of Virtual Box. What operating system is it installed on?  It may not be compliant with the operating system.  One think you might try (no guarantee) is to install the newest version of Virtual Box, see if it overwrites the old version  and if so, uninstall VB again.

Answer (score 0):

Virtual Box is MSI based so on my computer, I navigate to the native `uninstall` key:

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{E07820B4-EDC1-44FC-B1AE-D1D0F347F16B}`
Which is for this version:

`DisplayVersion` = `6.4`

`UninstallString` = `MsiExec.exe /I{E07820B4-EDC1-44FC-B1AE-D1D0F347F16B}`

So when you're in Programs and Features, that list is populated by these keys for entries where the `SystemComponent` value is not set to `1`.

When you run the uninstall, in this case, it is running the above `UninstallString` command.

To get better logging of the uninstall and help diagnose your problem, I would suggest you do as follows:

1. Launch an Administrative Command prompt.
2. Open the registry at the above location to find the UninstallString value for your version of Virtual Box.  Note: This GUID is the ProductCode of the application. It may be different for you.
3. Type: `MsiExec.exe /I{E07820B4-EDC1-44FC-B1AE-D1D0F347F16B} /L*V c:\vbuninstall.txt`
4. Choose the uninstall option when prompted.
5. After the failure, take a look in the log file c:\vbuninstall.txt to see why.

If you need help, link the log from the question.  I will take a look and update the answer with more information.